# What's the best way to save User data (email+password) into your app?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have an application where the user can log in but i don't want the user to enter his credentials every time he wants to use the application. 1 time would be sufficient but how(and whats the best way) to save 2 strings that i can revive by starting the application.

Comment: See this thread as well: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523627/storing-passwords-in-iphone-applications/524144#524144](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523627/storing-passwords-in-iphone-applications/524144#524144)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The iPhone has a [keychain API](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html) just like OS X. Or you could just store them using [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) which would be easier but less secure.

Comment: Please don't store them using NSUserDefaults, you wouldn't want too expose passwords of your users when they for example lose their iPhone.

Comment: Just be aware that the Keychain uses Triple-DES, in case that matters.