# How do you store your client credentials in your Oauth iPhone App?

Tags: ios, authentication, oauth

So I've been reading some documentation on Oauth, and I understand the concept and the way Oauth works, but I am having trouble understanding something...

On the following [website](http://hueniverse.com/oauth/guide/security/), I took this excerpt (see emphasis):

> In everyday web transactions, the most common credential used is the username-password combination. OAuth’s primary goal is to allow delegated access to private resources. This is done using two sets of credentials: **the client identifies itself using its client identifier and client secret**, while the resource owner is identified by an access token and token secret. Each set can be thought of as a username-password pair (**one for the application** and one for the end-user).

So lets use Instagram as an example,

- Client = Instagram iPhone App
- Server = Instagram Server
- Resource Owner = Instagram User

My question is, how does the client store the client identifier and client secret inside the iPhone app when [Storing passwords in iPhone applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523627/storing-passwords-in-iphone-applications) is known to be completely insecure... Where does one store the client identifiers and client secret securely for oauth access?

Comment: possible duplicate of [OAuth secrets in mobile apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934187/oauth-secrets-in-mobile-apps)